# How can specify time location for CreatedAt when selecting results?

Tags: timezone, go-gorm

I have a table with CreatedAt fild as "timestamp with timezone"

when I select rows I have entities with CreatedAt with time zone in my location, and I want to have it as UTC.

```
    type app struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID
    CreatedAt time.Time
    }

    db, err := gorm.Open(
    postgres.Open(databaseURL),
    &gorm.Config{},
    )
    if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }

    a := &app{}
    db.Table("applications").Take(a)
    fmt.Println(a.CreatedAt)
```

it prints "2023-02-01 11:26:29.554589 +0300 MSK"
and I would like to have "2023-02-01 08:26:29.554589 +0000 UTC"

Is there some option for that (gorm-v2)?

gorm-v1 retrieves as UTC, by the way. And gorm-v2 - in current location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set timezone to UTC: os.Setenv("TZ", "UTC")

Gorm v2 then retrieves datatime in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using timestamp with timezone, but here are a few solutions to this issue. The solution I found useful ([see here](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4834))  is to provide a NowFunc when connecting to the database:

```
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(connectionString), &gorm.Config{
            Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
            NowFunc: func() time.Time {
                utc, _ := time.LoadLocation("")
                return time.Now().In(utc)
            },
        })
```

Then you can see that your data is saved according to your table specifications and it is displayed as you expected in Go.

Comment: I set createdAt manually as UTC (already existing code) and in DB table createdAt is also in UTC. I can see it by selecting row directly in sql.

Problem is when I get this row with gorm-v2

Comment: @СергейТяпкин set your timezone to UTC: os.Setenv("TZ", "UTC").

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. It works for me. Thank you!